# google calendar python API library ignores timeMin

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to get calendar events via Google calendar API v3 (python library)

The problem is it ignores my query on timeMax and timeMin:

Code snippet:

```
service = gcal.service
first = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')).replace(microsecond=0)
last = first + datetime.timedelta(hours=4)
sfirst = first.isoformat()
slast = last.isoformat()
events = service.events().list(
                calendarId='primary', timeMax=slast, timeMin=sfirst,   maxResults=10,
                singleEvents=True,
                orderBy='startTime'
            ).execute()
print("First: {}".format(sfirst))
print("Last: {}".format(slast))
for i in events['items']:
   print (i['start'])
```

Output:

```
First: 2016-09-14T16:46:44+02:00
Last: 2016-09-14T20:46:44+02:00
{'date': '2016-09-14'}
{'dateTime': '2016-09-14T13:30:00+02:00'}
```

As you see, second event's start time is out of the boundaries that were queried.

I saw similar issues on stackoverflow (in other lanugages) but still don't know what is actually wrong. 
Seems follow the documentation, Use timezones, etc, even removed microseconds

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Looking at the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python), it seems your dateformat did not use utcnow(). Can you try using that in the date format?

Comment: I just follow what is written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list). Timezone is there, UTC is just a particular case. BTW what i finally did is just filtered out the result items with "wrong" start time in the code, but it is not how it's supposed to work...

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior. In the "Try this API" panel things work perfectly, but calling through the `google-api-python-client` package does not seem to respect timeMin.